# Creating or Modifying SecurityDescriptors in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: windows

OK, the Windows dev platform I have is a Windows XP box and a copy of Visual C++ 6.0. I'm trying to create or modify security descriptors for a service. My initial thought from other answers (and some reading) was that I should use ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor to setup my security descriptor.

Except...my install of VC++ 6.0 lacks the headers for this function (sddl.h according to MSDN).

Can anyone point me to other APIs for creating/modifying Security Descriptors? I'd be happy if I could walk through an existing one (I can QueryServiceObjectSecurity) and just eliminate certain users, but I can't figure out how to do that just looking at MSDN.

Alternately, if someone could point me in the direction of how to call this function without proper headers, that would be fine.

Obvious answer rebuttal: I can (and will) make an attempt to get IT to install a newer version of VC++ on my system, but the last time I asked IT about anything significant it took 7 weeks for them to respond. Since I'd like to get this done in the next week or two, I think IT is not going to fix this question for me in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you don't need a newer compiler, just an updated SDK. In reality, VC++ 6 is old enough that it may have trouble parsing the headers for a current SDK though.

As an alternative to that, you could declare pointers to the correct types of functions in your code, then use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to get the addresses of the correct functions, then call the functions via those pointers.

As an aside, however, I'd point out that I doubt what you've envisioned will work. I've never tried to do exactly what you're trying, so it's always possible I'm wrong, but every time I've done *anything* manipulating security descriptors, DACLs, SACLs, or anything similar in Windows, the code's ended up *considerably* longer and more complex than it initially seemed like it should. Even something extremely trivial generally requires at least a couple hundred lines of code...

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of GetProcAddress, but it's been a long time since I last used it. Based on what you've said, I'm going to go with the simplest possible thing - I'll just make use of a pre-declared SDDL string. Less to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [DCOMPerm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242178(VS.60).aspx) sample, it has handles the DACL/ACE and other structures you are going to run into - thats where i started when i created a set of classes to handle this for our COM installations - and as @jerry coffin said it ended up being a lot of code.

You'll have to download the SDK to get the sample.